# DocuSign website cant call webhook listener

Tags: docusignapi

I try to receive signed file from Docusing using web hook listener, before it working file , but form 31-05-2022 Docusing cant call our web hook listener.
When i check log from Connect menu, i got this error on bottom

> 6/22/2022 | 3:52:07 pm
> Error: Exception in EnvelopeIntegration.RunIntegration: ac08432f-18c4-471d-8720-caaf78fe4dfc :: No URI :: Error - Invalid URI: The URI is empty.;

This is the code i pass web hook listener url.

```
 Dim eventNotification = New EventNotification()
 eveventNotification.Url ="https://www.sample.com/webhook/default.aspx"   
 eventNotification.RequireAcknowledgment = "true"
 eventNotification.IncludeDocuments = "true"
 eventNotification.LoggingEnabled = "true"
```

May i know exact problem ? This final success receive from web listener is 5/30/2022, after that all are failure.

Thanks and Regards
Aravind

Comment: How did you set the webhook? can you share your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error typically means you're using envelope-level EventNotifications, but you're not actually defining a valid `url` parameter when you're sending an envelope.

You'll want to check your Envelope Definition in your code, but you can also use [API Request Logging](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=jux1643235969954&topicId=poz1578456669909.html&_LANG=enus) to capture what your application is sending to DocuSign