# DocuSign webhook listener not trigger from DocuSign site once file signed

Tags: vb.net, docusignapi

We have created web-hook listener for receive the signed file.In our production account, in one day 10 to 15 files is signed, out of 10 files one or two files not receive in web-hook listener.I mean form Docusing site not trigger the our web-hook listener, we added logs when trigger webhook and store in log file.So out of 10 files, 2 files is missing to receive signed file in webhook.But in Docusing login we can see all are completed in manage tab (sent) and in logs in setting page, we see correct webhook url passed for that envelope.

And one more thing, our webhook listener keep on triggering , based on log entry every 1 or 2mins it triggered , but we never pass that url to anyone, only configure in eventNotification Url using following code.Nobody know that url , but how it keep on triggered ?

```
 Dim eventNotification = New EventNotification()
 eventNotification.Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("EventHandlerURL").ToString().Trim
```

Is there any way to find where the problem ?

Regards

Aravind

Comment: Is this the entire code? you don't have events etc. inside? do you do this for every envelope you send? can you post all the code you have to create envelopes?

Comment: Hi Inbar, thanks for reply , i already get help from you and successfully move to production (live) , everything working fine, problem is some of the signed file not receive in our webhook listener. we added log for monitor incoming response.

Comment: May need to contact customer support

Comment: I see Drew already answered your prior question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72714315/docusing-website-cant-call-webhook-listener